# System Web MVC WebViewPage is not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webview, uipageviewcontroller

> I having this error but I cant find the way to help it
>
> > Server Error in '/' Application.
> >
> > Configuration Error
> >
> > Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
> >
> > **Parser Error Message: 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.**
> >
> > Source Error:

```
<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, 
Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   </httpModules>
     **<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">** 
     <namespaces>
    <add namespace="GridMvc" />
```

Source File: C:\app\web.config    Line: 32

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` namespace added at the wrong place (as shown by `httpModules` used before the line causing problem). The correct place to add respective namespace is in a web.config file inside `Views` folder under `system.web.webPages.razor` element, as shown below:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="GridMvc" />
        <!-- other namespaces -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

The `pages` element under `system.web` is primarily intended for webforms project configuration (under `System.Web.UI.Page` namespace), which often contains 2 attributes (`validateRequest` & `clientIDMode`):

```
<pages validateRequest="true" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

To use MVC version of `pageBaseType` attribute, you need to check if current `pages` element exists inside `system.web.webPages.razor`. In this case you added the namespace incorrectly under `system.web`, which doesn't inherit `System.Web.Mvc` namespace & throwing disallowed namespace error.